# Optimize SQL request

Tags: sql, join, request

I want to optimize my SQL request because it looks so bad and it's a little bit slow.

I have two tables :

**ORDERS**

```
order_id | order_number | order_date | customer_id | commercial_id | product_id
```

**CUSTOMERS**

```
customer_id | customer_name
```

When a commercial make an order for a customer, I have entries like this in my **ORDERS** table :

```
1 | 6750 | 2021-08-09 | 854 | 64 | 12

1 | 6750 | 2021-08-09 | 854 | 64 | 32

1 | 6750 | 2021-08-09 | 854 | 64 | 41
```

I'm making an array to display list of commercial's orders :

```
order_number, order_date, customer_name
```

And to do this here is my code

```
//Getting all orders of the commercial

$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT distinct order_number, order_date FROM orders WHERE commercial_id = :commercial_id ORDER BY order_date DESC");
$req->BindParam(':commercial_id',$commercial_id);   
$req->execute();
$distinct_orders = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$orders = [];

//Looping all orders number and get the customer name

foreach($distinct_orders as $distinct_order){
    $req = $bdd->prepare("
        SELECT O.*, C.customer_name
        FROM orders O
        LEFT JOIN customers C
        ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
        WHERE O.order_number = :order_number
    ");
    $req->BindParam(':order_number',$distinct_order['order_number']);   
    $req->execute();
    $order = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $orders[$order['order_number']] = [
        'order_number'      => $order['order_number'],
        'order_date'        => $order['order_date'],
        'customer_name'     => $order['customer_name']
    ];
}
```

I know it's so bad and I'm sure that there is a way to join to make it easier.

Comment: why you do 2 queries ? just add the commercial_id in the second query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Steven : The first request is for unify the orders number with the DISTINCT.

For exemple, if I have an order with 10 products, I will have 10 entries in my table with the same order_number but different product_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORD.order_number, ORD.order_date, CUS.customer_id, CUS.customer_name
FROM orders ORD
LEFT JOIN customers CUS
ON ORD.customer_id = CUS.customer_id
WHERE ORD.commercial_id = :commercial_id
ORDER BY ORD.order_number DESC
```

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

just use the commercial_id in the second query. Something like this :

```php
$orders = [];

$req = $bdd->prepare("
        SELECT O.*, C.customer_name
        FROM orders O
        LEFT JOIN customers C
        ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
        WHERE O.commercial_id = :commercial_id
");
$req->BindParam(':commercial_id',$commercial_id);   
$req->execute();
$order = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
//Looping all orders number and get the customer name
foreach($order as $order){
    $orders[$order['order_number']] = [
        'order_number'      => $order['order_number'],
        'order_date'        => $order['order_date'],
        'customer_name'     => $order['customer_name']
    ];
}
```

Comment: It's better, one less request.
but I would really like to do without the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine this into a single query as:

```
SELECT O.*, C.customer_name
FROM orders O LEFT JOIN
     customers C
     ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
WHERE O.order_number IN (SELECT o2
                         FROM orders o2
                         WHERE o2.commercial_id = :commercial_id
                         ORDER BY order_date DESC
                        );
```

For this query, you want an index on `orders(commercial_id, order_date desc)`.

Your question doesn't specify the structure of your data.  There might be simpler ways to express this.  For instance, is `order_number` unique?

Comment: OP is doing FetchAll for the first query so there's no need for the `limit 1`

Comment: @AndrewSayer . . . I seem to have invented the `limit 1`.  I thought it was in the original query.